# domain driven design proxy, cheating?

Tags: php, design-patterns, proxy, doctrine, domain-driven-design

I am quite new to DDD and have some fundamental problems that i cant really understand.

Consider we have a **User** entity. A User has some **Friend**'s (one to Many).

There are 2 possible solutions to fetch the friends.

Solution 1:
user.getFriends()

The Problem here is that all the friends have to be loaded or I am forced to use a Proxy.
If i use a Proxy it feels for me like cheating because the entity must not have an instance of the Repository. Can the Proxy have one?

Solution 2:
Avoid the getFriends Method and load the Friends Based on the User Repository, like:
userRepository.getFriendsOf(user)

This could sometimes be a good idea, but where to stop here? Whats about an AddressRepository for accessing user Addresses, or ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should look at it from perspective of Aggregate Roots.

In case of user.getFriends() - the user seem to be AR with associated friends which I don't think is correct. The definition of AR says "that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes". Friends are outside of the Boundary of user AR.

Considering the above the other option seem better - userRepository.getFriendsOf(user)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that either of them are correct.  I think from a DDD point of view, the code is supposed to use the *Ubiquitous Language* of the domain. In that regard, getters are frowned upon. 
Why are you getting the friends of a user?  The public methods of User should reflect the ubiquitous language.

For example if your domain is a social networking site, users should have methods to update status which will internally notify friends etc. How the User knows who its friends are or how they are queried  is hidden as an implementation detail.

Comment: "How the User knows who its friends are or how they are queried is hidden as an implementation detail."



the problem i have here is that the entity is responsible for loading such a relationship. but the entity shouldnt know any repository. 



so if i change some state in the entity the entity could be "obervable" or should i better use some hooks in the repository?

Comment: If your entity is responsible for maintaining the relationship then you need to store the friends in the User.  However, I would worry about how scalable that design is if a user has lots of friends.  the entity can still have getters and setters to be used to interact with the datastore but they shouldn't be used outside of the User class or however you are persisting

Comment: the entity doesnt care about persistence, so it's up the the repository how the entity is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is that you shouldn't use your domain model for querying.  So you do not want to be lazy-loading or applying any other fetching strategies.

You also need to identity your aggregates.  An aggregate is loaded in its entirety from the data store.

In your case if a `Friend` class can only ever exist in the context of a `User` then it is part and parcel of the `User` and its life-cycle is linked to that of the `User`.  That means that when the `User` is deleted (conceptually, as one probably would not want a hard delete) then the associated `Friend` instances are deleted also.

So if a `Friend` represent the association between users then it probably only contains the `User` Id.  So you could go with a list of Ids in that case.  This would depend on your domain.

I would guess that you very rarely would need to load the entire list of `User` instances that are friends of another user.  If you need related data you could implement a light-weight query layer.

Comment: In this case, how one can solve if Friend's list goes way too big and doesn't see fair to load in full?

Comment: My take on this has changed somewhat since this answer.  An aggregate really only needs to track those bits that are relevant to the consistency.  You'd need all the invariants to ensure your aggregate is still fine.  Anything else may be kept temporarily (transient) and may then be saved from the aggregate but perhaps never loaded back (like the `Friends` list).  I may very well simply manage the association between users (friends) in some more direct fashion as aggregates don't need to get involved; unless they contain some pertinent bits such as limits.  A data store can be used directly.

Comment: So you mean we don't need to save the complete list of friends but any data related to cover the invariant rule, if any. Makes sense.